WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage
I have deployed Alma Linux 9 and MariaDB 10.11.7 with Galera 4 on two AWS instances and all the ports and firewall rules are open between 2 instances, I set the proper wsrep options and I am still seeing the issue below.
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage: exit codes: 124 0
By the way , I have tried the same setup in my local laptop, it worked and SST happens and I am able to form the cluster. I see issues when deployed in cloud instances.. Can you please assist? I have been debugging this issue since a month.
